# Wordpress - get_post_format() returns nothing, if post format is 'aside'

Tags: php, wordpress, post, format

I have a problem regarding posts and post formats on Wordpress.

When I try to get the format of a post in the loop I get an empty return from `get_post_format()` if the format is 'aside'.

The response is also empty if I try to get the post object with `get_post()`.

Everything works if the format is set to default or gallery. The post formats are correctly registered and you can select all three formats in the backend interface, when you create a post.

Has anybody an idea, what the problem could be?

Would be great, if somebody could help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `functions.php` for the [supported post formats](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/post-formats/).

You can add the `'aside'` to it and everything will work fine.

Hope this help. SYA

Comment: The post format 'aside' is added correctly in the functions.php:

add_theme_support('post-formats', ['aside', 'gallery']);

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved. A content-aside.php existed in the theme, that I did overlook. Thanks anyway for the help.